# Cant remote desktop with dual montiors from Windows 10 pro to Windows 7 RDP protocol

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Don't know what I am doing wrong.  I have Windows 10 Pro, I select the Show options->Display tab and say use all monitors.  Everytime I only get one monitor.  I don't get it.  Is there something between windows 7 and windows 10 that I am not understanding?  Please help, I have become addicted to multiple monitors, and anything less than 2 > 3 when working is completely uncivilised.

Comment: A quick google search and maybe this [link](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-dual-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session-on-windows-7) will help you. See the `/span` and `/multimon` options. Also, check [technet mstsc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907.aspx) and [Configure Remote Desktop Access on Windows 7 Systems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx)

Comment: It turns out it was the resolution of my screens (> 2k).  When I turned them down I was able to log in and use all of my screens.